# How to add specific views in Coordinator Layout's NestedScrollView which will not scroll behind toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

- I want to have some views in NestedScrollView that will go behind the toolbar. 
  [Views above button will go behind toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDbMO.png)
- Below that there will be a relative layout holding two buttons (Which I don't want to go behind the toolbar)
  [These are the buttons that will be sticky on top. Below part will be scrollable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfUS7.png)
- After that there will be recyclerView having it's own scrolling properties.

Comment: Add more detail what you want to accomplish ex: screenshot

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged screenshots added

Comment: So that's the current state or what you try to do

Comment: Currently the buttons also go behind the toolbars. But I want them to be sticky @AhmedAbd-Elmeged

Comment: But your code in the question